# How to move one column values to another in pandas base on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame is given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        'per1':[np.nan, 'sa1', 'sa2', np.nan],
        'per2':['sa3', 'sa2', 'sa2', 'sa4']})
```

which looks like:

```
name  per1  per2

a     NaN   sa3
b     sa1   sa2
c     sa2   sa2
d     NaN   sa4
```

and I want to convert to the the outcome below by moving `per2` column values to `per1` which has null values.

```
name  per1  per2

a     sa3  
b     sa1  sa2
c     sa2  sa2
d     sa4
```

I have tried this one but it copy the per2 column value.

```
df['per1']=df['per1'].fillna(df['per2'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `loc`:

```
msk = df['per1'].isna()
df.loc[msk, ['per1', 'per2']] = df.loc[msk, ['per2', 'per1']].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
  name per1 per2
0    a  sa3  NaN
1    b  sa1  sa2
2    c  sa2  sa2
3    d  sa4  NaN
```